# Access Tableau thumbnails for views

Tags: jquery, tableau-api

I know there is an API in current version tableau which will help access view thumbnails, but it requires an authentication token in header. Is there a thumbnail url for view that I can call from javascript  without token in header that I can use in my customized website of tableau?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by playing with url, 
 + "/thumb/views/" + / +  will give you thumbnail without any need for authentication token